# Update item of json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json array

```
[{
    "sku": "5221",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 17.5,
    "desc": "5395 - Replenish Natural Hydrating Lotion 3.5oz"
}, {
    "sku": "11004",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 30.95,
    "desc": "150 - Q-Plus 16oz"
}]
```

i am getting this array inside $item php variable and decoding that array

```
$jsonDecode = json_decode($items, true);
echo 'before' . PHP_EOL;
print_r($jsonDecode);

foreach ($jsonDecode as $key => $obj) {
    if ($obj->sku == '11004') {
        $jsonDecode[$key]['qty'] = '5';
    }
}
print_r($jsonDecode);
```

now i want if sku is 11004 then qty of that index would be 5 .
but after using above code i got same array with same qty for that index.

how can i do so 
Please Help.

Comment: your json string doesn't seem to be valid. show the full json string

Comment: you want to update the quantity and then create new json?

Comment: yes @ChetanAmeta i want to update qty of same json with 11004 sku and then want to save in DB. i am print json decoded array two time 1st before implementing foreach and 2nd after implementing foreach but getting same array without any change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try below solution:

```
$json = '[{
    "sku": "5221",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 17.5,
    "desc": "5395 - Replenish Natural Hydrating Lotion 3.5oz"
}, {
    "sku": "11004",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 30.95,
    "desc": "150 - Q-Plus 16oz"
}]';

$array = json_decode($json, true);
//print_r($array);

foreach($array as &$a){
    if($a['sku'] == 11004){
        $a['qty'] = 5;
    }
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

**output:**

```
[{
    "sku": "5221",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 17.5,
    "desc": "5395 - Replenish Natural Hydrating Lotion 3.5oz"
}, {
    "sku": "11004",
    "qty": 5,
    "price": 30.95,
    "desc": "150 - Q-Plus 16oz"
}]
```

Comment: Tried but still getting same array without any qty change.

Comment: have you used `&` with val in foreach loop .... working fine for me.. have a look at https://3v4l.org/1IBIO

Comment: Worked dude thanks , but can you please tell me why we are using & here?

Comment: @KaranAdhikari -> By default, function arguments are passed by value (so that if the value of the argument within the function is changed, it does not get changed outside of the function). To allow a function to modify its arguments, they must be passed by reference.

To have an argument to a function always passed by reference, prepend an ampersand (&) to the argument name in the function definition. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: Thank you @ShriSuresh for clarification i really appreciate this.